# My this.props are undefined on handleSubmit and other function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I do not know why my this.props are showing undefined on handleSubmit. I have done everything possible. When I log state in mapStateToProps, I see what the action has dispatched, but this.props is not taking it.

This is what I get (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqVrY.jpg) in logger when I enter the wrong details
I have searched online but no clue. I have debugged this for hours

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import qs from 'qs';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Outer from '../templates/outer';
import history from '../../_helpers/history';
import routes from '../../services/urls';
import apiRequest from '../../services/api';
import loginUser from '../../redux/actions/authentication.action';
import { LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../../redux/constants/authentication.constants';
import alertActions from '../../redux/actions/alert.actions';


class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fields: {},
            errors: {},
            loginError: '',
            submitted: false,
        };
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(alertActions.clear());
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(field, e) {
        const { fields } = this.state;
        fields[field] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ fields });
    }

    handleValidation() {
        const { fields } = this.state;
        const errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;

        // Login code
        if (!fields.code) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.code = 'This field is required';
        }

        // Password
        if (!fields.password) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors.password = 'This field is required';
        }

        this.setState({ errors });
        return formIsValid;
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { code, password } = this.state.fields;
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        if (this.handleValidation()) {
            this.setState({ submitted: true });
            const payload = {
                email: code,
                // level: 'SYSTEM',
                password,
            };
            const { dispatch } = this.props;
            dispatch(loginUser(payload));
        } else {
            this.setState({ submitted: false });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { loginError, submitted } = this.state;
        return (
            <Outer>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="mt-5" />
                    {loginError
                    && <div className="alert alert-danger">{loginError}</div>
                    }
                    <label>Login Code</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'code')} value={this.state.fields.code || ''} />
                    <div className="text-danger mt-1 mb-1">{this.state.errors.code}</div>
                    <br />

                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')} value={this.state.fields.password || ''} />
                    <div className="text-danger mt-1 mb-1">{this.state.errors.password}</div>
                    <br />
                    <button
                        className="btn btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase"
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={submitted}
                    >
                        { !submitted ? 'Login to manage my cards' : 'loading...' }
                    </button>
                    <div className="row no-gutters mt-4">
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                            <NavLink to="/reset-password" className="grey">I have forgotten my password</NavLink>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </Outer>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.error(state);
    const { auth } = state.authentication;
    const { alert } = state.alert;
    return { auth, alert };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

store.js

```
export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware,
    ),
);
```

authentication.reducer.js

```
function loginReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
        return {
            user_status: LOGIN_REQUEST,
            user_data: action,
        };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
        return {
            user_status: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            user_data: action,
        };
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
        return {
            user_status: LOGIN_FAILURE,
            user_data: action,
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

export default loginReducer;
```

authentication.action.js

```
function loginUser(payload) {
    function request(user) { return { type: LOGIN_REQUEST, user }; }
    function success(response) { return { type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, response }; }
    function failure(error) { return { type: LOGIN_FAILURE, error }; }

    return (dispatch) => {
        // const request = apiRequest(routes.LOGIN, 'POST', qs.stringify(payload));
        // const ah = loginUser(qs.stringify(payload));
        // console.log(ah);
        dispatch(request(payload));
        const fetch = apiRequest(routes.LOGIN, 'POST', qs.stringify(payload));
        return fetch.then((response) => {
            switch (response.status) {
            case 400:
                dispatch(failure(response));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(response.data.description));
                break;
            case 200:
                if (response.data.code === 0) {
                    localStorage.setItem('qwplx44', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    dispatch(success(response.data));
                    history.push('/dashboard');
                    break;
                }
                dispatch(failure(response.data.description));
                dispatch(alertActions.error(response.data.description));
                break;
            default:
                return {};
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(failure(error.response.data.message));
            dispatch(alertActions.error(error.response.data.message.toString()));
            // return false;
        });
```

root-reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    authentication: loginReducer,
    alert: alertReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Please share fullCode on `LoginComponent`

Comment: Login component is the first snippet @Isaac

Comment: Are you using `connect()` from `react-redux`? If so, can you post your `mapDispatchToProps` function?

Comment: @Temi'Topsy'Bello: You did not share the full code. Please share how you import and how you export the component too

Comment: Login.js has been edited now @Isaac

Comment: I am using matchStateToProps @khan I have used the same steps in another project before and it worked

Comment: are you sure the request is good? meaning what is the api response from the actual request? what status did you get?

Comment: @JohnRuddell The structure of the API I am using actually returns 200 for invalid username/password for instance. Screenshot here https://imgur.com/a/DUhAdZo

Comment: You've probably not bound `handleValidation` to this. `this.handleValidation = this.handleValidation.bind(this);`

Comment: Even with that, doesnt work still @kontinuity

Comment: what isn't working? where are props undefined?

Comment: can you log props `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: Yes. Inside onSubmit function, immediately after the action dispatch dispatch(loginUser(payload)); console.log(this.props); shows nothing. I can see the action in logger as shown in (https://imgur.com/a/AXixWn9) @JohnRuddell

Comment: Yes, nothing shows there ```console.log(state);``` in mapStateToProps shows what I want. But ```console.log(this.props)``` does not. @diegought

Comment: can you debug it? just add a line, type in `debugger`. and inspect from there

Comment: @JohnRuddell done this https://imgur.com/a/tqh8WOi I added ```console.log({props: this.props});
            console.log('PROPS ARE MEANT TO BE SHOWN BEFORE THIS LINE');```

Comment: @Temi'Topsy'Bello It sounds like you are trying to inspect the value of `this.props` right after you call `dispatch(loginUser(payload))`. The request is async so you cant do that. You have to wait for the data to change. This waiting period you should show a loading spinner or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't connecting your component correctly. You are trying to destruct keys out of the state that aren't there. I don't see a key called `auth` on your loginReducer. 
So this line `const { auth } = state.authentication;` would return undefined. That is why when logging props `auth` is undefined.

Instead just pluck what you want from state and you can alias `authentication` as `auth` while destructuring :)

```
const mapStateToProps = ({authentication: auth, alert}) => ({
    auth,
    alert
})
```

If you are trying to use the data stored in your reducer after making the request, then you should use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { auth: prevAuth } = prevProps
  const { auth } = this.props

  if (auth.user_status && ((!prevAuth.user_status && auth.user_status) || prevAuth.user_status !== auth.user_status)) {
    // TODO handle response from api here
    /* ex
      if (auth.user_status === LOGIN_FAILURE) {
        this.setState({loginFailure: auth.user_data})
      }
    */
  }
}
```

Few other things.

You aren't binding `handleValidation` to the class, but are trying to access state. 
You are calling `this.setState({ submitted: true });` twice in `handleSubmit`. Second one is redundant and not needed. 
I would refactor your `apiRequest` to handle the `qs.stringify` and the error / auth / response status handling, so you dont have to write out that same stuff for every api call :)

Comment: While your response was followed, it auth and alert only changed to empty objects when i log ```this.props``` see here https://imgur.com/JrOQb44

Comment: well, initially you set the reducer's state to be an empty object no? `function loginReducer(state = {}, action) {`. If you are trying to access what you set in the reducer, you need to use `componentDidUpdate` or `await` the request / dispatching so you have the values from your async request

Comment: This is right. You saved me. componentDidUpdate did the trick. but then, I have had this work in another project. I seriously don't know :)

Comment: If it's not making an API request then you could probably get away with doing that. I'd still stick with using async await though